# After inserting one element in HashMap<String,Object>() i can't insert anything more - always duplicate key

Tags: java, insert, hashmap, key, duplicates

Let's say I have:

```
private HashMap<String, IDevice> virtualMachineDevices;

public VirtualMachine(String virtualMachineId, String virtualMachineName, long virtualMachineMemory, int virtualMachineCPUs) {
        setVirtualMachineId(virtualMachineId);
        setVirtualMachineName(virtualMachineName);
        this.virtualMachineMemory = virtualMachineMemory;
        setVirtualMachineNumberOfCPU(virtualMachineCPUs);
        this.virtualMachineDevices = new HashMap<String, IDevice>();
    }

    public void addDevice(IDevice newDevice) throws DuplicateDeviceIdException {
        if (virtualMachineDevices.containsKey(newDevice.getDeviceId())) {
            throw new DuplicateDeviceIdException();
        } else {
            virtualMachineDevices.put(newDevice.getDeviceId(), newDevice);
        }
    }
```

After I insert one `[key,object]` pair, I can't insert more because `DuplicateDeviceIdException` is thrown.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong except you may be getting duplicate device ids, Have you tried printing Ids before adding to the map?

Comment: I fixed it in a different way, created the device in a different way and changed the key input, it is like totally the same (or so it seems to a noob like me) but it works, thanks for help